# Numerical Triple Integration won't evaluate

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate the following triple integral numerically to no avail:

```
N[Refine[NIntegrate[NIntegrate[x * Integrate[
     u *r^2.75*Exp[-3*u]/(5*u*r^2.75 + x^4), {u, 0, x^2}], {x, 0, 
     1000}], {r, 0, 1000}], {Element[u, Reals], Element[x, Reals], 
   Element[r, Reals], u >= 0, x >= 0, r >= 0}]]
```

As indicated, the three variables (u, r, x) are real and non-negative. The basic function is smooth, has no singularities and is so simple that the integral as a whole should come out a positive real number. However, Mathematica (R) returns a complex 2-line expression instead.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `NIntegrate[x*u*r^2.75*Exp[-3*u]/(5*u*r^2.75 + x^4), {x, 0, 1000}, {u, 0, 
  x^2}, {r, 0, 1000}]`.

Comment: Wow! This is really worth trying.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me when I reversed the first two integrals. In my case, I have to integrate wrt u {u,0,x^2} first, and this causes Mathematica to give the message: "u = x^2 is not a valid limit of integration"

Answer (score 3):

You can do the innermost integral analytically, but as formulated, `Integrate` gets lost in the complex plane and produces a horrible `ConditionalExpression` that may be formally right but appears difficult to evaluate numerically. Give `Integrate` the assumptions directly, and it works better. I also urge you not to feed approximate numbers like `2.75` to symbolic methods: use exact rationals.

```
uint = Integrate[u*r^(11/4)*Exp[-3*u]/(5*u*r^(11/4) + x^4), {u, 0, x^2}, 
   Assumptions -> {r >= 0, x >= 0}]
```

yielding:

```
(1/75)*(5 - 5/E^(3*x^2) + (3*E^((3*x^4)/(5*r^(11/4)))*x^4*
       ExpIntegralEi[-((3*x^4)/(5*r^(11/4)))])/r^(11/4) - 
  (3*E^((3*x^4)/(5*r^(11/4)))*x^4*
  ExpIntegralEi[-3*x^2 - (3*x^4)/(5*r^(11/4))])/
    r^(11/4))
```

Not too horrible. Have a look:

```
Plot3D[uint, {r, 0, 1000}, {x, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Then, to do the rest numerically, you must do both dimensions in one go. You can't do the inner integration numerically with the variable of the outer integration free. The integrand must be a number with no free variables.

```
NIntegrate[x*uint, {x, 0, 1000}, {r, 0, 1000}]
```

yields routine complaints about convergence, but yields an answer that seems reasonable:

```
2.70936*10^7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful answer.  What irritates me though is that why Mathematica "gets lost in the complex plane", as you cleverly phrased it, when it was told all the variables are non-negative _real_ numbers.

Comment: You didn't tell `Integrate` that they were real, you told that to `Refine`. `Integrate` could not make use of the information.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, John; your answers are remarkably insightful and very much to the point.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong here. I applied your advice to the letter, yet I got a _complex_ number. First, the innermost integral is made analytical and told that all variables are real:
Integrate[r * Exp[-1/250000*Pi*u]/(1 + (1/3)*u^-2*x^4), {u, 0, x^2}, 
 Assumptions -> {Element[u, Reals], Element[x, Reals],

This gave an excessively long expression with complex numbers in it. Then, I did the other two integrals numerically in one go:

Element[r, Reals], u >= 0, x >= 0, r >= 0}]
NIntegrate[%, {x, 0, 100}, {r, 0, 100}]

This gave this _complex_ number:
6.26311*10^8 - 1.64745*10^-8 i

Comment: The result above came from a fresh version 11.3 kernel. Note that it is not uncommon to see small parasitic imaginary parts showing up in real calculations, although I'm not seeing that here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are using nested `(N)Integrate`'s. This computes for less than a second on my laptop:

```
NIntegrate[
 x*u*r^2.75*Exp[-3*u]/(5*u*r^2.75 + x^4), {x, 0, 1000}, {u, 0, 
  x^2}, {r, 0, 1000}]

(* 90740.6 *)
```

Comment: Nested `NIntegrate` doesn't work for the reason I gave in my answer. If `Integrate` can do the inner integration symbolically, it's usually faster to numerically integrate the `Integrate` result.

Comment: @Anton Antonov
You are right; your integral works perfectly because it integrates wrt x first.  In my case, however,  I want to integrate wrt u {u,0,x^2} first, and this seems to be problematic.